# Why does using a pointer with a class with no default constructor work here and not using no pointer

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I have a class like the following...

```
MyClass {
  public:
    int myA;
    int myB;

    MyClass(int a, int b) {
      myA = a;
      myB = b;
    }
};
```

in my `main.cpp` file I try to use this class and it works.

```
MyClass myClass(3, 4);
```

I also try to do the following...

```
MyClass myClass;
```

but that doesn't work and says there is not default constructor. I understand that under the hood there is no default constructor being supplied because I supplied `MyClass` with a constructor.

I noticed that to achieve what I want I can do the following...

```
MyClass *myClass;
```

and that does work. I don't understand why this is the case and would like an explanation if anyone can please help.

Comment: You have declared a pointer variable that points to nothing. You have not constructed an instance of the class.

Comment: MyClass *myClass doesn't call any constructor at all. It just declares a pointer (with unitialized value!).

Comment: *"to achieve what I want I can"* -- I do not see a description of what you want in your question. Your question only describes your attempted solution to get what you want, then focuses on the secondary issue of your attempted solution. This looks suspiciously like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), but I suppose idle curiosity could be in play...

Comment: @JaMiT I was just curious as to how it works. I'm actually reading about pointers now and referencing, etc. It is becoming much clearer. I would have been more descriptive but I was not sure of the terminology.

Answer (score 3):

```
MyClass *myClass;
```

This line does not call *any* constructor for your class, because it does *not* create an instance. It just creates a pointer, pointing to nothing in particular. If you want it to point to an instance of your class, you have to call a constructor to create one and you will have the same problem as before.

Comment: I see thanks for the response.